# Determining which key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress

This function has many applications. I have a TextBox control. How to display keys that the user pressed. For example pressed CTRL and z in the TextBox control should appear "Ctrl + Z"? It's WPF application. Thanks.

Now i'm trying like this:

```
  private void txtHotKey_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        txtHotKey.Text += e.Key.ToString();
        txtHotKey.Text += "+";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Now if I pressed Ctrl and Z in the textbox appear "Ctrl+Z+". Then press Ctrl and A. Will be "Ctrl+Z+Ctrl+A+". It's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.aspx) you get passed to the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx) event handler of the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx)?
It's got plenty of properties that identify which key has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following post with example code: [Capture key press events with WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/308b62af-9969-47a0-8805-22eb786177f0)

Does it help you? You can either attach yourself to the grid (or your textbox) with the `KeyDown` event handler or you could use a `Window_KeyDown` method.